# “Wir folgen den Steinen” – why “Steinen”?

Tags: noun, accusative, inflection, grammar-identification

I know, the plural form of *Stein* is *Steine.* But why is it *Steinen* in the following?

> Wir folgen den Steinen.

It looks like *Steine* also gets inflected to accusative form.

Comment: I think when there are some basic questions about grammar, it would be helpful for people learning German and it wouldn't harm. So I hope this question be left as it is. The + votes show this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some German verbs take dative objects, even though the equivalent English verbs take (accusative) direct objects; *folgen* is one of these verbs. So *Steinen* is dative plural in your sentence.

Comment: I see. My web dictionary doesn't show  there is a dative form of Stein. Not every noun has the dative form, does it?

Comment: @ChanKim: Dative plural forms of nouns add _n_, unless the plural form of the noun already ends in _n_ or _s_. Something like a grammar book would be more helpful for you in this matter than a dictionary, because dictionaries are primarily concerned with lexicology not morphology. I think pretty much all dictionaries take it for granted that you know this rule, and therefore they give just the non-dative plural form.

Comment: Ah thanks. I am studyng German in my leisure time and learning German grammar too. I'll look it up.